# I can't do Arrays with Doubles/Ints? (Java)

Tags: java

So I have:

```
String[] program = {"total", "grade", "average"};

System.out.println(program[1]);
```

It prints out "grade".

But why can't I do this with doubles?

```
Double[] program = {total, grade, average};
```

I want to be able to use these variables later on. Like total = 4, then program[0].

Comment: What does *I cannot do this* mean? Do you get a compile error? If so, what exactly does it say? Do you have a runtime-exception? If so, please post the stack trace. What type do `total`, `grade` and `average` have? Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you declared and initialized the variables `total`, `grade` and `average` before adding them to your `Double` array?

Comment: @Nicklas no      lllllllllllllllllll

Comment: I would recommend a [basic Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) since OP seems to be pretty new to Java and programming overall.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OPs answer to my previous comment, the problem is that the variables `total`, `grade` and `average` aren't declared and initialized before they are used for initializing the array `Double[] program`.

To fix this, all you have to do is declare and initialize the variables before using them, like this:

```
// Initialize variables
double total = 70.0;
double grade = 10.0;
double average = total / grade;

// Initialize an array of size 3 containing the 3 doubles
double[] program = {total, grade, average};
```

Please note that I've declared all the variables using *primitive* datatypes (camelCase / lowercase) instead of their `Object` representation (PascalCase / Capitalized). This is preferred when you *don't* require the ability for the value of the variable to be `null`.

Comment: You could even write `Double[] program = {total, grade, average}` due to [Auto(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). But regardless, I think that OP's problem is more a basic understanding of Java.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer to clarify why I'm using primitive datatypes.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably assigning the variables to the array when they are not yet initialized.

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. You need to make sure you put numbers when you declare your array. The following works:

```
    Double[] a = new Double[] { 101d, 200d, 300d };
    System.out.println(a[0]);
```

or

```
    Double[] a = new Double[] { 101.0, 2.0, 30.0 };
    System.out.println(a[0]);
```

The 'd' or '.0' is only a way to inform the compiler that this number is not an integer.

Comment: Is 101d a number or a variable?

Comment: In my case it's a number. The problem, is that you need to tell the compiler that this number is a Double (and not an integer), so you add the 'd' after to remove the ambiguity on the type. Try my example, it will print 101. I haven't try, but I believe you could also try to